# Reading in a file and performing string manipulation

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, csv, io

In a question I answered I posted the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    fstream iFile("names.txt", ios::in);

    // This does not work so replacing with code that does
    // iFile >> file;

    // This is not the best way.
    // But the closest to the intention of the original post.

    // Get size of file.
    ifile.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    std::streampos          length = ifile.tellg();
    ifile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

    // Copy file into string.
    std::string       file(length, '\0');
    ifile.read(&buffer[0],length);

    // Original code continues.

    std::istringstream ss(file);
    std::string token;

    std::vector<std::string> names;

    while(std::getline(ss, token, ',')) {
        names.push_back(token);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
         auto it = std::remove_if(names[i].begin(), names[i].end(), [&] (char c) { return c == '"'; });
         names[i] = std::string(names[i].begin(), it);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "names["<<i<<"]: " << names[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Would this be inefficient for larger files? Would it be better if I read the file into one string, did all the manipulation on that, and then put it into a vector?

Comment: Is the code all inside `main()`? You can't have free-floating code like that in C++.

Comment: This code obviously does not work without main. So unless people have objects I will add main() around all the code so we are at least commenting on the code in the same way.

Comment: It still obviously does not work because `iFile >> file;` that is not doing very much. It reads a single space separated word. So I am going to change that to read the whole file into a string.

Comment: Now it works (as best it can).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code looks a little wild. I'd tame it like this:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::remove
#include <fstream>   // for std::ifstream
#include <string>    // for std::string and std::getline
#include <utility>   // for std::move
#include <vector>    // for std::vector

std::ifstream infile("thefile.txt");    // we don't really care where you got the name from

std::vector<std::string> names;

for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line, ','); )
{
    line.erase(std::remove(line.begin(), line.end(), '"'), line.end());
    names.push_back(std::move(line));
}

// done
```

A few points to note:

- Keep it simple. Don't overthink.
- Use ready-made algorithms, don't reinvent wheels (`std::remove` removes values).
- Include what you use (`std::string`, `std::getline`).
- Use algorithms, don't hand-roll your own loops. (erase/remove)
- Understand what algorithms can do for you (don't hand-write your own "erase"). Get familiar with the standard library.
- Don't leak scopes. The `line` string is only needed within the loop, and no further.
- Efficiency tip: You can *move* from the `line` string that you no longer need and save yourself a copy. Also, we process everything in one step; no need to loop repeatedly.

Furthermore, I suggest factoring this logic into a file:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize_file(std::string const & filename, char delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // ...

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<std::string> names = tokenize_file("thefile.txt", ',');
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of constructing an `fstream`, reading it all into a `string` (which is misleadingly named `file`, by the way), and creating an `istringstream` from that, why not just create an `ifstream` and call `getline` on it directly?

You appear to be trying to parse a CSV file where the fields may be double quoted.  If that is your intention, then simply deleting all `"` characters is the wrong behaviour.  See [RFC 4180](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) for commonly accepted quoting rules for CSV documents.  Consider using a [CSV parsing library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV_application_support) instead of rolling your own CSV parser.

Your code would be clearer if you unquoted each `token` before adding it to `names`.

Comment: Totally agree on using CSV parsing library. CSV is one of those badly (not though through enough) defined formats that has a billion edge cases that you would never think about yourself. The simple case is trivial but doing it correctly for all cases is exceptionally hard.